# How do you integrate $2\pi \int_0^4{4\sqrt{x}\sqrt{1+\frac{9}{4x}}dx}$

Tags: calculus, integration

$2\pi \int_0^4{4\sqrt{x}\sqrt{1+\frac{9}{4x}}dx}$

I tried u-substitution but it did not seem to work. Could you please tell me how to approach this problem? Thank you.

Comment: Suggestion:  Make your problem as simple as possible, e.g., eliminate the useless $2 \pi 4$.  You'll get more help, and perhaps see solutions yourself.

Answer (score 5):

You do not need the $u$-substitution here. Note that $\sqrt x\sqrt{1+\frac9{4x}}=\sqrt{x+\frac 94}$ and that an antiderivative of $\sqrt{x+\frac 94}$ is $\frac23\left(x+\frac94\right)^{3/2}$.

Comment: Thank you, Mr. Santos, but could you please tell me how $\sqrt{x}\sqrt{1+\frac{9}{4x}}$ is equivalent to $\sqrt{x + \frac{9}{4}}$? I apologize for my lack of knowledge of the rules of radicals.

Comment: Beacaus$$\sqrt x\sqrt{1+\frac9{4x}}=\sqrt{x\left(1+\frac9{4x}\right)}=\sqrt{x+\frac94}.$$